# Import data with unusual date-time format

Tags: r, strptime

I try to import data generated by an instrument measuring aquatic oxygen concentration. A programmer wrote a function to import these files. One of the argument of the function is DateTimeFormat:

```
 read.AR2.mo2(
 filename,
 TimeZone = NA,
 DateTimeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M:%S"
)
```

However, the date-time format the software generated is in a different format, month and day don't have leading zeros. Here is an example: 9/5/2020/8:43:07 AM

I tried to specify another DateTimeFormat using strptime arguments such as:

```
 read.AR2.mo2(
 filename,
 TimeZone = NA,
 DateTimeFormat = "%m/%d/%Y/%H:%M:%S %p"
)
```

and

```
  read.AR2.mo2(
 filename,
 TimeZone = NA,
 DateTimeFormat = "%m/%e/%Y/%H:%M:%S %p"
)
```

but nothing worked (return NA in the column).

Do you know what strptime format I can specify to import these date-time?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `as.POSIXct("9/5/2020/8:43:07 AM", format="%m/%d/%Y/%H:%M:%S %p")` works without a problem.

Comment: Can you change it to `%m/%d/%Y/%I:%M:%S %p`

Comment: Yes, when I use as.POSIXCT it works too. I also changed according to akrun suggestion to respect the 12h format with AM/PM but it does not solve my problem. I contacted the editor of the function and he tried with one of my file using the same script and it works for him. I guess I have a different installation. Thank you for your help, I will continue to look for a solution and come back here when found.